# PrestaShop errors on frontend

Tags: php, prestashop

I have this PrestaShop install which shows the following errors on the front-end:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/username/public_html/modules/categoriesnc/categoriesnc.php on line 1677

Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/username/public_html/modules/categoriesnc/categoriesnc.php on line 1677
```

Line 1677 in categoriesnc.php has:

```
for ($i = 2; $i <= ($max_depth > 0 && $max_depth < $depth ? $max_depth : $depth) && array_key_exists('lev'.$i, $result[0]); $i++)
$breadcrumbs[] = $result[0]['lev'.$i];
```

Any advise on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn error reporting off to not see the message any more. But that is a custom non standard Prestashop module, so I would contact the developer with the error. They are just warning messages and they will not hurt anything if they are not addressed.